# Issue with DateListPlot and Dynamic List

Tags: dynamic

Imagine that we are getting readings from an external device (ie Arduino) at a given interval of time. We'll simulate the reading as follows.

```
getDataPoint[] := {DateList[], First@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1]}
dataList[myList_List, maxPoints_Integer] := 
         Module[{x}, x = Append[myList, getDataPoint[]]; 
         If[Length@x > maxPoints, Take[x, -maxPoints], x]]
data = {}
DateListPlot[ Dynamic[Refresh[data = dataList[data, 15], UpdateInterval -> 1,
TrackedSymbols -> {}]]]
```

Gives me the following error message

*DateListPlot::ntdt: The first argument to DateListPlot should be a list of pairs of dates and real values, a list of real values, or a list of several such lists*

If I add the command separately, it does render the chart. Of course, I don't want to display the list data being updated in the screen, just the chart.

```
Dynamic@DateListPlot[data, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: How can one call `data = dataList[data, 15]` when `data` itself does not exist as input? You should post complete self contained working code.

Comment: Forgot to add the line data={}. Now in place

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```
getDataPoint[] := {DateList[],First@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1]};

dataList[myList_List, maxPoints_Integer] := Module[{x},
  x = Append[myList, getDataPoint[]];
  If[Length@x > maxPoints, Take[x, -maxPoints], x]];

data = {};

Dynamic@DateListPlot[Refresh[data = dataList[data, 15], UpdateInterval -> 1, 
  TrackedSymbols -> {}], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed it does. Thanks @Nasser. :)